# Too many instances in Google App Engine for PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I have launched a new Android application and I have a Google AppEngine (PHP) module that supports it (to sync profile information to the cloud).

I have noticed that the instance hours used is too much. Could someone please advice me how I can configure the AppEngine to use very less number of instances so that I never overshoot the free number of instances quota of 28 hours per day?

Is there a way to limit the number of instances fired up parallely?
Will disabling threading (threadsafe=no) help?

I am new to Google AppEngine and cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't control, at least directly, how many instances your app will consume at any given time as App Engine will do its best to decide it for you.

Here is what you can do:

- Profile your application to understand how your code is using resources and work on shortening the time each request is using (the shorter your requests are, the less instances you will need).
- Set daily budget for your app. After the budget is exhausted, the app will stop serving traffic.
- Disable billing. After free 28 hours would be used, the app will stop serving traffic.

Comment: Thank you, I do understand the concept. But I am looking for any option. If I can let an instance run for 24 hours (and only one instance, let the other requests wait for the current one). I am thinking of setting a low timeout like 5-10 seconds max so that that each request doest stay for more than 10 seconds keeping the instance idle for the other requests. Also if I disable threads, will it force AE to use only one instance? Have you tried this one?

Comment: this answer is incorrect. you CAN control and put many limits, look for the xml configuration options. of course that means many users will get serving errors as your app consumes too many resources.

Comment: @ZigMandel -  perhaps, you should provide your own answer, if you believe you have one. By the way, for PHP it's app.yaml and not xml file.

Comment: @StuartLangley - you're absolutely right, ```threadsafe``` set as ```false``` will cause more instances, not less.

Comment: Thank you DoITInternational & @StuartLangley. My current configuration is threadsafe = true. Meanwhile I saw this somewhere 

`instance_class: B1
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1`

Will it work? Also will is there an option for timeout?

Comment: @MathewParet - This might work but not recommended if you have "spiky" traffic. If you won't have enough instances to handle the incoming traffic, your client app won't get response in a timely fashion and might not behave as expected.

Comment: I think the idea is he wants to run it for free, and drop additional traffic.

Comment: @StuartLangley - if that's the case, Set daily budget for the app should do the work for him.